# Forwarding a port to a local address using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, tunnel

I'm running a TeamSpeak 3 server on a home server. I would like to mask the IP address of the home server so I am using a VPS as an entry point to my TeamSpeak 3 server. I found a tutorial online that is perfect for my use case: https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/linux-setup-gre-tunnel. Unfortunately I'm having an issue with the last command and I don't know iptables enough to troubleshoot the issue. Please may someone help me with fixing this iptables command?

The command I'm stuck on is: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <VPS IP address> -p UDP -m UDP --dport 9987 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2`

The console response I get when trying to run this command is: `` iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match `UDP':No such file or directory ``.

Comment: looking https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=954123  it says don't bother with -m udp.

Comment: The command has completed without an error, thanks! Unfortunately I'm unable to connect to my TeamSpeak 3 server via the entry VPS. I'm unsure why.

Comment: maybe "teamspeak" have some documentation advising on making a secure setup.. (that allows teamspeak through)?